# Wrap comment reply text into a span tag

Tags: html, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

Drupal comment reply have the next structure

```
<li class="comment-reply first">
 <a href="/comment/reply/12/1">reply</a>
</li>
```

But I want the next structure

```
<li class="comment-reply first">
  <a href="/comment/reply/12/1">
    <span class="rep">reply</span>
  </a>
</li>
```

My question is with the [function comment_link](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!comment!comment.module/function/comment_links/7) I can change the markup of this link or I need use a hook or theme function

Comment: What theme are you using?

Comment: My own theme based in Omega theme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement [hook_comment_view](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!comment!comment.api.php/function/hook_comment_view/7) to alter the output of comments. You'll need to add this to a custom module in a .module file

```
<?php

function hook_comment_view($comment, $view_mode, $langcode) {
  foreach($comment->content['links']['comment']['#links'] as $delta => $link) {
    // Only apply this new markup to the reply link
    if(strpos($link['href'], 'comment/reply') === 0) {
      $title = $link['title'];
      $comment->content['links']['comment']['#links'][$delta]['title'] = '<span class="rep">' . $title . '</span>';
    }
  }
}
```

Remember to replace "hook" at the beginning of the function name to the name of your module. Example:

```
function mymodule_comment_view($comment, $view_mode, $langcode) {
```